# How to use dual sim WWAN

Tags: mobile-broadband, modem-manager, wwan

I am trying to use a dual sim "Sierra Wireless, Incorporated EM7455" PCIe module, the first sim has been working for a long time but now I want to build in redundancy / coverage (i.e. alternative operator)

I essentially have a single modem and 2 sim card slots for said modem, so how do I switch between the two sim cards with ease?

My Ubuntu 20.04 recognises there are two WWAN available logically so is it possible to use both in tandem? if so. how?

In short: How do I use 2 sim cards at once on ubuntu 20.04 using mmcli and/or nmcli apis

Comment: "so is it possible to use both in tandem?" to what purpose?

Comment: @24601 to route certain bits of traffic through each WWAN / network provider .... if that is not possible and only possible via switching then I can come up with a script once i am able to work out of to turn on / off one or the other